# HTML loading page à la blogger.com

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to determine the cleanest way to implement a brief loading screen that would be displayed to my site's visitors while JavaScript is loading some data behind the scenes, processing it and updating the DOM accordingly.

I like what blogger.com does with one of its themes, specifically [this one](http://blog.datomic.com/). It seems to completely fill the screen with a grey background with a spinny image on top, and then it fades out once all the underlying work is completed.

Does anybody happen to know how exactly they achieve that effect? I haven't gotten too far with just poking around in Firebug. Doesn't look like it's being hidden or removed from the DOM.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function removeOverlay(){
//code to remove the div waiting overlay
}
</script>


<body onload="removeOverlay()">

<div id='mainContainer'>

// this overlay style is in one word ugly, modify it to your style :p

<div id='waitiongOverlay' style='position:absolute;border:1px solid red; background:red; top:0; left:0; width:99%; height:99%; z-index:100;'></div>



</div>
</body>
```